# Why can't I print the loop value twice inside a for loop

Tags: java

I was making a for loop, and I noticed a strange problem.
Inside the for loop, I can make a System.out.println(i);
that prints out i, and it works perfectly.  But if I try
to add a second line that prints out i+1, I get an error,
saying 'i cannot be resolved to a variable'.

Why can't I print the value of 'i' twice inside the same 
for loop?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)

    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i+1); // This i returns an error that says that 'i cannot be resolved to a variable'

}
```

Comment: If your code was indented correctly, the reason would be obvious. The first `println` is inside your loop. The second is outside. This is why you should use `{}`. And proper indentation.

Comment: You need to wrap your statements inside `{ }`

Comment: include the curly brackets '{...}'

Comment: Thanks everybody!  Sorry I'm such an idiot! :()

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i+1);
} 
}
```

Whenever you do not use brackets **{ }** on a **for/if** etc **only the next line** is considered as contents of it. So in your code **only the first** print was considered as contents of for loop. To type more lines you need to use brackets {};

Answer (score 1):

In java, and many other languages, a block is marked by brakets such as these {}. Everything inside these is in a scope. If you skip the brakets for a loop (it doesn't matter which loop), only the next line is taken as the loop body. So, your code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
      System.out.println(i);
      System.out.println(i+1);
```

is equivalent to

```
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
     System.out.println(i);
  }
  System.out.println(i+1);
```

As yo can see, only one statement is inside the loop. The other one is outside. The error you are getting is because the variable "i" doesn't exist in that scope. It only exists inside the for loop.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was a most useful comment.

Comment: Not "equivalent" ..it is not python

Answer (score 0):

You are missing brackets:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {

        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(i+1); // This i returns an error that says that 'i cannot be resolved to a variable'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include both lines inside braces:

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i+1); 
}
```

Because `i` variable scope is limited to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both statements within the braces because you have more than one statement and the second statement is outside of loop.

Try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args){  

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        System.out.println(i);

        System.out.println(i+1);
    } 

}
```